# resize DIV matching the new content with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, fade

I have a DIV which shows one image at once coming from an ajax script, the images are all different in height and are showed with fadeIn/fadeOut (just for the  tag)

How can I allow to resize the DIV (that contains the img tag of course) "sliding" based on the new content before the images that fadein changes the DIV height very rudely? :P

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the jquery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function to change the width and height of the div.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well do Something like this

```
$(".change").click(function() {
  $(".mydiv").fadeOut('slow');
  $(".myimg").attr("src",'');    
  $(".myimg").attr("src","linktonewimage.jpg");
  var newheight = $(".myimg").height();    
  $(".mydiv").css("height",newheight+"px");
  $(".mydiv").fadeIn('slow');
});
```

I am assuming you have a `<img>` tag with `myimg` class inside a `div` with `mydiv` class.

Check the [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/VrKNH/)

Comment: $(".myimg").attr("src","linktonewimage.jpg");

what does this do? consider that the img tags come from a PHP via AJAX

Comment: @Sandro, it changes the `src` attribute of your image, resulting in a change of image. I will setup a demo for you to see this.

Comment: in your demo the div doesn't slide

Comment: @Sandro, I am only trying to demonstrate the resizing of `<div>` besides I am not sure, what you mean by sliding, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/)? It might do all you are talking about here, sans having to write it yourself. It can be heavily customized with CSS and uses animation.